# WPF Datagrid autogenerated columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have bound a datatable to a datagrid in WPF. Now on clicking a row in the grid I need to have a window pop up. But for that, I need to first change a column in the datagrid to be a hyperlink. Any ideas on how to do that?

```
<DataGrid Name="dgStep3Details" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,39,7,8" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, ElementName=step3Window,Path=dsDetails}" />
```

If I can't change an autogenerated column to hyperlink, is there a way to add a button to each row instead?

Thanks
Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it was really hard to create hyperlink columns to autogenerated datagrid. What I eventually did was this - create buttons to the grid on the fly and then attach a routed event for the same based on the autogenerate event of the datagrid where I shall put my code. I didn't want my code to be hardcoded to the columns and now I'm flexible by changing the datatable on the fly. Here is the code:

```
 private void dgStep3Details_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (grid == null)
            return;
        DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col.Header = "More Details";
        FrameworkElementFactory myButton = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button), "btnMoreDetails");
        myButton.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, "Details");
        myButton.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(btnMoreDetails_Click));
        DataTemplate cellTempl = new DataTemplate();
        //myButton.SetValue(Button.CommandParameterProperty, ((System.Data.DataRowView)((dgStep3Details.Items).CurrentItem)).Row.ItemArray[0]);
        cellTempl.VisualTree = myButton;
        col.CellTemplate = cellTempl;
        dgStep3Details.Columns.Add(col);

    }
    public void btnMoreDetails_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Button scrButton = e.Source as Button;
        string currentDetailsKey = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(dgStep3Details.Items[dgStep3Details.SelectedIndex])).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        // Pass the details key to the new window

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to get these advanced UI features out of autogenerated columns.  I think you'll either have to decide to program these columns in C# or VB.NET when you retrieve your data and tailor them the way you like, or you'll have to abandon the UI ideas you've mentioned.  Autogenerated columns just cannot do that.

However, you could change your approach.  Try checking into events like MouseLeftButtonDown, etc.  and see if you can simulate the behavior you want by other means.

Comment: Lane, thanks for your answer. I agree, I had to go with no auto-generation and then try ItemDataTemplates to style my columns to be hyperlinked. I also thought of using this approach http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984262(v=VS.71).aspx but this also uses no autogenerated columns and hence went with the below solution